# field num_med cannot be modified

Tags: delphi

I've put this code in a speedbutonclick but when I'was trying to execute it I got the message that said field num_med cannot be modified 
the code is

```
   procedure TAddEdiMedForm.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
   begin
   DM.MedicamentTable.InsertRecord([ Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.text,
                                            Edit4.Text, Edit5.Text, Edit6.Text, 
   Edit7.Text]);
   CloseModal;                                              
   end;
```

Comment: What component are you using (DM.MedicamentTable)?

Comment: I'm using TFDQUERY

Comment: What field type is your `num_med` field, in the FDQuery and the RDMS behind it and is it marked Read Only in either case?

Comment: field type is int

Comment: But what about Read Only?

Comment: the readonly is false of course

Comment: I'm not sure about the "of course"  You have not provided sufficient info for anyone to possibly diagnose your problem.  So I've voted to close it, as have 2 other people so far.  If it gets 5 close votes, no-one will be able to post an answer even if they know what the problem is.

Comment: it's not about the readonly at all but it about the field's  properties 
Actually I found out why I got that message because it's a primary key and auto increment that's all anyway thanks a lot for all of you

Comment: There is no problem with the num_med being a primary key as long as the value you attempt to insert is unique at the time you attempt to insert it.  The problem is trying to insert a value for an AutoInc field.  You need to retreive that value (from the server) after the new row is inserted. not try and force a value from the client side!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is trying to insert a value for an AutoInc field, which you are trying to do with your `InsertRecord` statement. You need to retrieve the AutoInc value (from the server) after the new row is inserted, not try and force a value from the client side!

Since you can't specify a value for the AutoInc field when you add a new row, you need to avoid using `InsertRecord`.  Instead, call `Insert` on tthe dataset, populate the other (non-AutoInc) fields by individual assignment statements, then call `Post`.  How best to retrieve the AutoInc value depends on the back-end server, though FireDAC usually does a pretty good job of doing this for you - look up how to get the value from the Online Help or google it.

You should have mentioned that the `Num_med` field is an AutoInc in your q, not blithely say that it is an `Int` field in a comment in reply to a query for info you should have supplied in the first place.  In future, please exercise a bit of consideration for readers here by including all relevant info in your initial q.